# Prove that any finite dimensional complex vector space has a conjugate linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

This is an exercise in my linear algebra textbook. I considered the isomorphism $v\rightarrow\bar{v}$ but it might not be a linear operator since it maps $V$ to $\bar{V}$.

A map $L$ is conjugate linear if $L(u+v) = L(u)+L(v)$ and $L(av) = \bar{a}L(v)$.

Comment: I think $\overline{V}\subset V$ by the definition of complex vector space. Hence your construction is correct.

Comment: Can you explain why $\bar{V}\subset V$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by $\overline{V}$ and by $\overline{v}$ ?

Let $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$. If $v \in V$ then there are (uniquely determined)  $c_1,...,c_n \in \mathbb C$ such that

$v=c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n$.

Now define

$L(v):=\overline{c_1}v_1+...+\overline{c_n}v_n$.